# Android app for reading data from external USB-Device

Tags: android, usb, communication

OK i know there are much threads about this topic. But most of em are like 2 years old. Because of that and the fact of new developments from googles side like ADK and stuff, im starting this question again.

All i want to know is, whether it is possible to establish a USB connection to an USB-Device now or not. Like to open a stream to receive the data from a sensor. Think about a device which can be the USB-Host and sends data permanently. All i wanna do is to grab that data.

Im using a smartphone with Android 2.3.6.

Are there any APIs now for this version? Or i have to go a way which includes a modification for the linux kernel or the usage of arduino or a similar interface? Because i would like to avoid that.

Comment: have you read this? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Most usb stuff starts coming into play with 3.0 > but I believe its back ported to 2.3 (not sure on it) but basically yes it is possible now. If you can get your device to be a usb host device you shouldn't have a problem, I use an acer iconia a500, running ics, I have a picaxe connected to an ftdi chip feeding me sensor data, once you have the basics sorted out its easy, if you go through my questions and find the usb related ones you should get a lot of information, ill link you if you want to the questions?

In short its entirely possible with the newer versions of Android, however back porting that functionality might cost you the same in time as it would in money to buy a new tablet or phone.

Heres everything I've talked about with usb on here... this stuff should save you a few hours I think [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1174869+[usb]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1174869%20%5Busb%5D)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But i have some questions.. With Android 2.3.4 the classes like UsbManager should be accessable through the Google APIs Add-On. But i cant access em. Thats bad news because it seems there is no way for me to get this class? Is this class part of ICS?

Comment: Usb manager should only be available for api 12 and above, which is android 3.1.x >

Comment: From what I read the manufacture is the one the implements the usb support library, which means it needs to be there in the first place, if you cant access them your device doesn't have these library's, maybe there is a custom rom that does? Otherwise a new device would be what you need.

Comment: I think for me the only way to get access to the required classes is a costum rom. so i will try that in the next days. Thx for your advices. Maybe this isnt the last post from me.